# AngularJS - Dynamic Ternary Operator

Tags: angularjs

I've some elements created by ng-repeat. I'm trying to assign dynamic class to them like :

```
<div ng-repeat="X in Xel">
     <div ng-repeat="Y in Yel">
          <img src="..." ng-class="trackKind(X,Y) == 1 ? 'A' : 'B'" />
     </div>
</div>
```

This ternary operator works at the page loading.
I've assigned to an other element the following code :

```
<div ng-click="changeTrack(X,Y)">Change</div>
```

**changeTrack()** works to change the *trackKind* value of the element in the array but the ng-class is not refreshed...

First question : Does Angular could work like this ?
Second question : If yes, what do I have to do ?

Kind regards,

NivekLR

Comment: To answer the first question: Yes angular could work like this. To answer the second, it is best for you to post `trackKind()` and `changeTrack()` source code

Comment: When you "inspect" the element (in dev tools), you should be able to see what class is applied to the element after your click. If you don't see your class applied then something might be wrong with the code, if you do, then maybe doing a $scope.$apply would work. Alternatively, putting the logic into ngstyle has solved some of these sorts of problems. I remember one such case while working on a project at Google (where ngstyle is frowned upon), where nobody could explain what appeared to be a straightforward class swap wasn't working, but ngstyle worked perfectly.

Comment: As long as ```changeTrack()``` makes  ```trackKind()``` return a different value, your code should work.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Actually I found an error in my code... It works fine !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply an error in my code... Thanks to all !